# Minecraft Forge for java edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

So, I wanted to mod my minecraft and I found out you had to use forge to do so. After downloading forge for 1.15.2, and WITHOUT looking anything up I figured you had to set it up and open it with the Minecraft launcher which is a bit incorrect since it is not loading up or anything and it won’t allow me to open Forge up with anything else. I’ve tried deleting and re-downloading Forge but it keeps coming up with the Minecraft Launcher since i can’t remove it. What am i supposed to do ?

Comment: Twitch also launcher provides a good wait to install mods for Minecraft out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Forge `.jar` file you downloaded. It is likely to be an installer, which will add itself to your Minecraft launcher.

Comment: Yes but the $100 question no-one answers is how do you find your Java executable to run the d@#n thing? I searched out the Java executable in the Minecraft folders and tried several `.exe` files in there but none of them seem to work and bring up an interface like in the videos?

Comment: @NeilG the Java executable itself isnt related to minecraft, and so isnt found in the minecraft directory. Java itself should be located at C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath/java.exe. If not, download it.

Comment: ^ When Java is installed and ran for the first time, it should automatically associate with the .jar filetype. Did you open Minecraft at least once before trying to install Forge?

Comment: Thanks @AMJ , but actually Minecraft *does* install a copy of Java itself, and that can be found in the Minecraft install directory.

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to associate `java.exe` with the `jar` file type, but the correct file to associate is `javaw.exe`. To fix associations quickly I recommend you download `jarfix.exe` and run it. It's got several options for batch / repeated use should your set up require that, and ... you'll see. This I believe is the author's download point (and hence most reliable) https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html